# Как сделать, чтобы результат записывался скажем в главный div?

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста. Имею поле поиска и объект:

```js
var object = { 
    "N01 - Number 01": {name: "N01 - Number 01"},
    "N15 - Number 15": {name: "N15 - Number 15"}
};

var form = document.querySelector('#form-search');

form.onsubmit = function(){ 
  
  var value = this.querySelector('#form-input-search').value.trim();
  var valid = null;
  
  if(value.match(/^\N[0-9]+.+[0-9]+$/)){
    valid = value.match(/^\N[0-9]+.+[0-9]+$/);
  } else {
    var source = "N{{search}} - Number {{search}}";
    source = source.replace(/{{search}}/g, value);
    valid = source.match(/^\N[0-9]+.+[0-9]+$/);
  }
    
  if(valid){
    
    if(object[valid]){
      console.log(object[valid]);
    } else {
      console.log("поиск не дал результатов");
    }
    
  } else {
    console.log("неверный формат");
  }
  return false;
  
}
```

```html
<form id="form-search">
  <input type="text" id="form-input-search">
  <button>Поиск</button>
</form>

<div class="main><p>Здесь должен быть результат</p></div>
```

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия на enter или submit был осуществлён переход на страницу по URN и в div>p записался результат поиска.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Искать необходимо в объекте object?

Comment: Да, поиск там и ищет, я немогу отобразить результат в  div-e.

Comment: Мне вот сказали буквально так: "(нажатие на кнопку или поиск представления в списке) вызывался метод javascript, который записывает имя страницы и значение urn в основной div?". Впервые сталкиваюсь с urn и не знаю, что с ней делать.

Comment: для вывода результата на страницу надо сделать так: находим в dom нужный нам контейнер, `let result = document.querySelector('.main');` записываем в него результат`tesult.textContent = "текст";`

Comment: Ок, это сработало, а как сделать переход на эту страницу?

Comment: опишите что вы хотите сделать более подробно, стек используемых технологий. поиск выполняется на сервере или же на клиенте? как выглядит результат? что из себя представляет страница для вывода результата поиска

Comment: Я использую только чистый JS и HTML. Страница вывода результата поиска является такой же страницей, как и страница ввода поиска, например, на страница ввода представляется из себя пустой div, после ввода поиска я записываю в этот пустой div результат поиска(поиск удался), но мне не только записывать результат, но и перейти на эту страницу.
Поиск, на данный момент, выполнятся на клиенте, но желательно было бы узнать, как это будет работать и на сервере для дальнейщего развития. 
Поиск осуществляется из имеющихся в объекте значений, если ввод совпадает с значением объекста, то поиск удался.

Comment: для описанного вами примера я могу придумать только следующее: на странице с поисковой формой подписываемся на событие `submit` в котором делаем [редирект](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/5610621) на страницу отображения результатов. в строке адреса передаем то что надо найти... логика поиска и отображения результатов реализовываются на этой странице. получаем то что надо найти из [строки адреса](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979995/5610621), ищем, выводим результат. P.S. решение как мне кажется должно работать, может быть есть варианты проще, сам не так что бы силен в веб разработке